# Draw in a complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Draw z in a complex plane, for which: $Re\left( \frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z+1}\right)>0$

No idea. Tried it all, but it becomes too complicated to sketch it.

Comment: Solve $Re(\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z+1}) = 0$. it should give you $Re(z)= 0$  or $|z|=1$

Answer (score 3):

Hint. We have that
$$\frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z+1}=\frac{2z}{z^2-1}
=\frac{2z\overline{(z^2-1)}}{|z^2-1|^2}=\frac{2z(\overline{z}^2-1)}{|z^2-1|^2}=\frac{2(|z|^2\overline{z}-z)}{|z^2-1|^2}.$$
Now 
$$0<\mbox{Re}\left( \frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z+1}\right) \Leftrightarrow 0<\mbox{Re}(|z|^2\overline{z}-z)=|z|^2\mbox{Re}(\overline{z})-\mbox{Re}(z)=(|z|^2-1)\mbox{Re}(z).$$Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of the domain is formed by the points such that the real part is zero.

$$\frac{2z}{z^2-1}=\frac1{it}$$ (the inverse was used for convenience).

Solving the quadratic equation for $z$,

$$z=\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}+it,$$

which is the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.